# Update table inside stored procedure updates all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following simple three lines at the end of a stored procedure:

```
UPDATE `imthreadmember`
   SET `lastUpdate`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 WHERE `threadId` = threadId;
```

However running this inside the proc, updates ALL rows in `imthreadmember`.
Running the same three lines in the console, updates only the ones with that `threadId`.
Inserting a `select threadId;` just before this statement returns the correct id.

I'm at my its end to figure out how to solve this.

The rows in `imthreadmember` were created earlier in the same proc, but as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can only be used as default once per table I have to update this column separately, the default goes to the `created` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of your variable is the same as the name of the column.  By MySQL's scoping rules, the column is being compared to itself.

It is a good habit to prepend *all* variables used in stored procedures with something like `v_`.  So the query should look like:

```
UPDATE `imthreadmember`
   SET `lastUpdate`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 WHERE `threadId` = v_threadId;
```

And, as a corollary, to never name a column starting with `v_`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I though I was "safe" with the weird quotation marks mysql uses. I'll mark the answer as accepted once StackOverflow allows me to.

Comment: @A.Grandt . . . If it makes you feel any better, I've made this mistake as well (and I'm guessing almost everyone who has used variables in MySQL has as well).